# Display current session name in mink

Tags: phantomjs, behat, mink, zombie.js

I am doing some tests with `zombie.js` and `phantom.js`, I would like to display my active session name before each test. Which method can I use?

With behat 3.0 and mink 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hooks](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/3.hooks.html). BeforeSuite, AfterSuite, BeforeFeature, AfterFeature, BeforeScenario, AfterScenario, BeforeStep, AfterStep

Example

```
/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
 public static function prepare(SuiteEvent $event)
 {
     // prepare system for test suite
     // before it runs
 }

 /**
  * @AfterScenario @database
  */
 public function cleanDB(ScenarioEvent $event)
 {
     // clean database after scenarios,
     // tagged with @database
 }
```

If your class extends `MinkContext` then you can dump your session with: `$this->getSession()`.

If your class extends `BehatContext` then you can dump your session with: `$this->getMainContext()->getSession()`